Anaconda, conda, Jupyter Notebooks relationship?
I know that Jupyter Notebook is open source software, but for the longest time, I've been using Anaconda to install and run it as suggested by Python instructors I've had and the Jupyter documentation. However, we just found out I'm not eligible for the free version because of the size of company I work at.
Can anyone explain to me the differences between Anaconda, conda, and Jupyter? If I just install Jupyter, how / will my experience be different without the Anaconda running in the background? Perhaps I can install conda as a package manager (making !pip install pandas work in Jupyter) and forego Anaconda? The structure of a coding environment is something that has always eluded me, and I'm trying to figure out alternatives if my company won't pay for my access to Anaconda.
How will my experience change if I stop using Anaconda? Will I be spending a lot of time figuring out my environment and not actually doing my work? For context, I teach data visualization and analysis, so I need access to things like pandas, matplotlib, etc.

yeah, conda is more like a package manager (but with parallel version of python, and also including GNU R, Javascript, etc.). Anaconda is the company and also a GUI interface (and they provide conda command). Jupyther is just the notebook part (linked also with ipython). Things are also interconnected (historically, and personally as main developers/founders/etc.)

Anaconda is a distribution. It is an all-in-one package of Python, various Python packages, a package / environment manager (conda), and some other tools (Jupyter, Spyder, etc.).
Conda is a package / environment manager. It can set up different environments for your various projects, installs your desired package, and figures out what other packages need to be installed as dependencies.
Anaconda is mostly made up of free open-source stuff, including the tools you want (conda, Jupyter, matplotlib, pandas, etc.), so there's nothing stopping you from assembling all the free parts yourself.
At this point, people are going to be opinionated about how to best do this, but using miniconda will give you basically an identical experience.

Download miniconda (completely free)
Remove the defaults channel for packages (which requires a license) and switch to a free channel like conda-forge. Another SO question covers this.

Anaconda also has a blog detailing free usage of conda

good overview, instead of 1. and 2., you can also go the direct route and install miniforge directly (basically the same as miniconda, but only conda-forge set as channel)
